# Automate input to brute-force a program running in cli with Python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, brute-force

I'm currently trying to complete all levels on Over the Wire's Bandit 'wargame'.

One of the levels (level 24), requires that I connect to a port, on which a daemon is running. This daemon asks to input a password and a 4-digit pin. The password is already known (it is provided at the end of the previous level), the pin is unknown. The indication is that it's necessary to 'brute-force' it.

Entering a wrong pin results in this message:  "Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again.".

I decided to write a python script that automates the process. The script would: 
1) Connect to the port via netcat
2) Enter the password and a randomly generated pin
3) Read the output, and, if the word 'again' is in it (meaning the pin is wrong), repeat via a loop, until the pin is guessed.

But although my script runs and connects, it fails to communicate with the daemon, once the connection to its port is established.

All I get is the daemon's prompt, requesting password and pin.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess
import random


# Initialise variables

pin = ''

output = "Wrong! Please enter the correct pincode. Try again."


# Connect to the port
def connect_to_port():
    subprocess.call(["nc localhost 30002"], shell=True)


# Generate pin
# TO DO: skip pins that were proven incorrect
def generate_pin():
    pin = ''
    pin_len = 0
    while pin_len < 4:
        pin += str(random.randint(0, 9))   
        pin_len += 1 
    return pin   


# Connect to port
# Loop: check if 'again' is in 'output',
# if it is, generate a pin and input password and pin
def main():
    connect_to_port()
    while 'again' in output:
        pin = generate_pin()
        out = subprocess.check_output(["UoMYTrfrBFHyQXmg6gzctqAwOmw1IohZ", pin])
        output = out.decode("utf-8")

main()
```

I suspect I'm not using the `subprocess` module correctly, but I can't really understand how. Why is my script not working?

Forgive my rudimentary use of the relevant terminology.

EDIT: I see the use of `subprocess.check_out()` is all wrong. What I'd need, as suggested in the answers and comments, is to open a PIPE and use `communicate()` to write to the subprocess's `stdin` (modifying the pin each time) and read its `stdout`, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: If the process is asking you to enter the pin via stdin, maybe you need to use `subprocess.Popen.communicate`.

Comment: Not cool at all, giving out the keys and your answers on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not here to help you brute-force servers

Answer (score 3):

The netcat needs to be opened once during the conversation and then multiple reads and writes need to be performed.
If you want to be able to read and write data to the subprocess, you will need to create a PIPE so use the `Popen` interface, then you can use `communicate()`.

Given how trivial this is, why not just open a socket directly in python?

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('localhost', 30002))
data = sock.recv(64)
sock.send(pin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, achampion. How would I go about using `communicate()`, once I've created a PIPE in `Popen`? It would have to read from the subprocess's stdout and write to its stdin (modifying the pin each time). I've been trying to read up on these topics, but I can't quite understand it.

Comment: `pipe = subprocess.Popen(('nc', 'localhost', '30002'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE); output = pipe.communicate(input)`

Comment: @user2331291: it is much faster to use several sockets here than spawning a child process for each pin, especially if the daemon does not disconnect after the wrong attempt.